# Authenticating for two endpoints apis

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, endpoints, google-api-js-client

I'm building a small app using javaScript.
I have two endpoints apis I'm trying to use in the app - each one of them is used by other apps that don't need the other api (so I don't want to combine them into one big api).

I can't find a way to Oauth2 authenticate for both of them using two different client_ids.
Is it possible? If so, how?

It seems like gapi.auth supports only one token etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use web workers?

Comment: I've considered that, It's a bit of an overkill for my needs,
currently I used a hacky solution and in the future if I'll need anything more I guess webworker is the best solution.

But I was looking for a supported solution using gapi client.

Thanks though!